# What is the difference between "Apply" and "OK" when changing settings in File Explorer on windows?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-10-upgrade

When changing File Explorer settings in Windows, a dialog appears, and there are two options: *"Apply"* and *"OK"* (image below). However, it seems not to matter which one is clicked. Both options apply the settings.

Is there a difference between *"Apply"* and *"OK"*? what's the difference?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ok* does the action and closes the dialog, *Cancel* closes the dialog without changes. *Apply* applies your changes but leaves the dialog open in case you want to make more changes.

Answer (score 1):

Apply changes the settings but does not close the window. You can think of it as "OK, but does not close the window."

If you Apply and Cancel you will get the same result as OK. It will not revert the changes.

Apply is useful if you want to test different options and see their effects.